# webscraping error with python3 only with some websites

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

This code works for websites like google and yahoo and returns 'good'

```
import urllib.request as ur
#url="http://www.evga.com"
#url="http://www.asus.com/us/"
url="http://www.google.com"
import urllib.error as ure

try:
    conn = ur.urlopen(url)
except ure.HTTPError as e:
    # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
    # ...
    print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code))
except ure.URLError as e:
    # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
    # ...
    print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason))
else:
    # 200
    # ...
    print('good')
```

but for asus gives error 403 and for EVGA gives no response at all.
How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a classic headers problem. urllib is not the best idea because you'll have a lot of implementation problems. Trust me URLLIB is a mess...

For web scraping I recommend either `requests` or `selenium`. The first one is a good start.

Let me share a `requests` version of your code

```
import requests
url="http://www.evga.com"
#url="http://www.asus.com/us/"
#url="http://www.google.com"

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

Yields:

```
200
```

I noticed `"http://www.evga.com"` is a troublemaker but using headers you'll have all under control.

More info about requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: thank you for that. interestingly, some pages redirect the request and still give 200. try the url    url="https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=4G-P5-3999-KR"

Comment: I guess I have to figure out how to know if I am getting redirected. A whole OTHER problem.

Comment: Check out Selenium. Although it takes more resources, could help for a step by step scraping.